# INDEX only pulling one row of data from database

Tags: cs50, finance

For the life of me I cannot get my index page to properly display the data from my database. I have tried multiple methods and research on several sites. I'm thinking it is something right in front of my face, but right now I can't see the forest through the trees. I have included my code below.

Application:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():

    users = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])
    quotes = {}

    for symbol in stocks:
        quotes[symbol["symbol"]] = lookup(symbol["symbol"])

    return render_template ("index.html", quotes=quotes,stocks=stocks, symbol=symbol)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th> Symbol</th>
            <th> Current Share Price</th>
            <th> Shares Owned</th>
            <th> Shares Owned Value</th>
        </tr>

        {% for stock in stocks %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{symbol.symbol}}</td>
             <td>{{quotes[stock.symbol]["price"] | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{symbol.shares}}</td>
            <td>{{symbol.total_price}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally here is a screenshot of my index.html as it generates now:
[image: index]

And the data in my database table:
[image]

As you can see, the table displays the symbol, shares and total price from only one of the transactions. It shows the correct updated price for each stock, but I can't get it to pull the correct data from the table. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more clear. What is the issue here? I did not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`symbol` has the value of the last iteration of `for symbol in stocks:`. Looks like the html should be creating the td elements from `stock` (`{% for stock in stocks %}`) not from `symbol`.

Suggestion to simplify:

In the `for symbol in stocks:` loop in the .py, add a key to the `symbol` dictionary for price. That would render the `quotes` object unnecessary and the `stocks` list would be self contained.